# Integrating Fast OBD Readings and GPS

Tags: obd-ii, fuel-consumption, gps

I'm working on a project to look at fuel consumption on different roads and I need the OBD reader to log the GPS coordinates every time it takes a reading.
I'm looking at instantaneous fuel consumption, so I also need it to be reading the parameters rather quickly.

My Autotap software takes 70ms per reading per parameter, so the 7 parameters I need take almost a half second to log which isn't enough resolution.
Any advice on how to get more frequent readings, and how to incorporate GPS coordinates?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be useful to mention what 7 parameters you wish to track. Also, see [this question](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/6463/reading-obd2-too-fast?rq=1)

Comment: Yeah, I should have mentioned. We plan to track vehicle speed, engine speed (RPM), fuel injector pulsewidth, mass air flow, the lambda value, and possibly NOx or other emissions related data available when we test with heavy trucks.